# Is there a way to keep the Preview Tab always visible? even when editing non xml code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have an ultrawide screen and I work, at some point, with the screen split in 2 editors. The leftmost panel is the file tree, then panel with the Activity kotlin file and then the xml of such activity.

When I change focus from the xml file to the kotlin file the preview tab disappears, only to appear again when I focus on the xml again.

**Is there any hidden option to have the preview tab visible with the latest selected xml layout?**

None of the options available (right-click) work as I expect it to work. Furthermore, even when I completely extract the preview tab from the IDE it disappears when no layout file is focused.

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, the preview is a sub-tool of the layout editor, which is why it goes away when you switch to another editor tab.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought so too, but since I technically still have the layout editor open (not focused, but open) I would expect to be able to keep it open :S